# Structural or sensitivity analysis of multivariate time series with multiple subjects

Tags: r, time-series, python, multivariate-analysis, multilevel-analysis

Sorry if this isn't explained in the best way. I have very basic knowledge of time series analysis so my question may sound very simplistic or might be missing the big picture of this type of analysis.

I have data set of multiple time series (5 variables) for about 22000 subjects. I have 6-20 observations for each time series. The subjects can be divided into a few categorical variables as well (some random and some fixed). My aim is understand the relationship between the variables rather than forecasting. I was hoping to perform the analysis in python and/or R.

I have tried using the `mlVAR` package in R to fit a multi-level VAR and was able to get some good results from the temporal, contemporaneous and between-subject networks. However, the number of observations I have for some subjects is less than the recommended minimum (>20 observations) for using this R package. Is there anyway to get around this or a different approach I should take?

At first I wanted to apply some version of a VAR (maybe Bayesian VAR as the number of observations is fairly small) and then look at the unit impulse responses or forecast error variation decomposition. However, I am unsure of how to apply a VAR if I have a time series for each subject. I was wondering if I could group the data using `gts` and `mts` in R, but I was unsure if that was even possible. Also, can UIR and FEVD analysis be applied to a grouped time series?

Any feedback or ideas would be greatly appreciated.